# How to change the existing User model with User calling API in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.4 project which doesn't have any tables which actually fetch data from APIs and get the work done.

I wanted to implement user authentication so I installed auth package using `<code>php artisan make:auth</code>` but Laravel auth package needs your user table and model to fetch the user data I want to replce that into my API means auth libraries should call my api to get the users data.

I am new in Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

what you want to achieve, is well documented in the [laravel docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)

> If you are not using a traditional relational database to store your users, you will need to extend Laravel with your own authentication user provider. - **Laravel docs**

Just create your own implementation of UserProvider and Authenticatable contracts (aka interfaces), and the auth will use your api as datasource.

Comment: Thank you. i will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of external authentication with LDAP:

[Howto: adminless LDAP authentification in Laravel](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)

The bit that you are most interested in is the function `attemptLogin()` inside  `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` (step 15).

There you check credentials, populate the `users` table and log the user in.

Answer (score -1):

Running `php artisan migrate` will create default tables including `users` table. After that you can implement User model to cover your needs.

Comment: he doesn't want to use a database, but only his api. So why should one create (migrate) tables, if one doesn't want to use it in the first place ... sorry but your answer sounds and smells like a 'hack-around' ... and not like a well planed architecture

Comment: @VikingCode agreed.